# Custom validations for GET mapping with pathvariable

Tags: java, spring-boot, validation, annotations, customvalidator

I want to do a custom validations using spring boot for below method.I want to validate "id" if it is other than a to z, 0 to 9 and - then I want to set error message and pass that in ResponseEntity.

```
@RestController
public class DataController {

    @Autowired      DataService dataService;

    @RequestMapping("/data/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Data> getData(@PathVariable String id)
    {       
        Data messages = dataService.getData(id, Data.DataFormat.ALL);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(messages, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't validate a single primitive type in parameter automatically.

You have to validate it manually.

Try this:

```
private static final Pattern ACCEPTED_CHARACTERS = Pattern.compile("^[a-z0-9\\-]+$");

@RequestMapping("/data/{id}")
public ResponseEntity<Data> getData(@PathVariable String id)
{       
    if (!ACCEPTED_CHARACTERS.matcher(id).matches()) {
      return new ResponseEntity<>("Your messge", YOUR CODE);
    }
    Data messages = dataService.getData(id, Data.DataFormat.ALL);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(messages, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

In real app, the test for pattern should be done in an utility class

Answer (score 1):

Another solution: You can use @Pattern and don't forget to use @Validated before your class.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("required url")
@Validated
public class yourClassName{
    @RequestMapping("/data/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Data> getData(@Valid @Pattern(regexp = "^[a-z0-9\\-]+$",message = "Your custom message") @PathVariable String id){       
        Data messages = dataService.getData(id, Data.DataFormat.ALL);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(messages, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```